# Go through a json data struture and check keys

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I am trying to go through an number of tab-separated words in a file and check if the key is in the structure (json):
The json object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name" : "Cypress Upload 1", 
    "Description" : "Cypress upload descrition 1"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Cypress Upload 2",
    "Description" : "Cypress upload descrition 2"
  }
]
```

The code looks like this:

```
cy.readFile(uploadPathFile).then((jData) => {
      cy.log(jData[0].Name);
      const objLn = Object.keys(jData).length;
      cy.get('@LASTDOWNLOADEDFILE').then((downFile) => {
        cy.readFile(downFile as unknown as string).then((txt) => {
          const lines = (txt as string).split('\t');
          for (let o = 0; o < objLn; o++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
              cy.log(`Key ${lines[i]}  ${jData[o].Name}`);
              if (jData[o].hasOwnProperty(lines[i])) {
                cy.log(`Found Key ${lines[i]}`);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

The first log: gives me the correct value of the Name key at position 0

```
18 log  Cypress Upload 1
```

The second log lists me all the names from the tab separated file:

```
...
21 log Key "ID" Cypress Upload 1
22 log Key "Name" Cypress Upload 1
23 log Key "Synonym 1" Cypress Upload 1
...
```

But it does not show the key found even though "Name" is there and jData[0].Name gives a value! Why is the line with "`if (jData[o].hasOwnProperty(lines[i])) {`" never true. I also tried "`if (jData[o][lines[i]]) {`"

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the problem:

The downloaded file contained apostrophes around the keys. You can see this in the second log. Removing them with

```
const strippedKy = lines[i].substring(1).slice(0,-1)
```

solved the problem!
The function hasOwnProperty is also not necessary. A simple

```
if ( jData[o][strippedKy] ) {
```

does it.